# How to get a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\to G$, for $G$ a non-trivial group?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group.

If $G$ is non-trivial, then there exists a non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\to G$.

How would one prove the above statement?

Comment: i know that there is a homomorphism if G is cyclic

Comment: Is Z the integers?

Comment: Pick any $g \in G, g≠1$. Then apply what you know to the subgroup $H$ generated by $g$.

Comment: Let $a\ne e$. and consider the subgroup generated by $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any element $\;1\neq x\in G\;$ , and define

$$f:\Bbb Z\to G\;,\;\;f(1):=x\;\implies\;f(m):=x^m\;$$